# Proof about abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that  $(G,*)$ is a group and that every element $a \in G$ satisfies $a*a=1$. Show that $(G,*)$ is abelian

if $(G,*)$ is abelian then $\forall a,b \in G, a*b=b*a$

$(a*b)=(b*b)*(b*a)$
$=(b*(b*b)*a)$
$=b*1*a$
$=(b*1)*a$
$=b*a$

How does that look?

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I will redo it

Comment: You`ve proved b*a=b*a

Comment: abba = ? Then another small step using a special fact about inverses in groups.

Comment: The suggestion from @snarfblaat works, but here's an alternative that might be easier. Under the assumption of your problem, $ab$ equals both $aabb$ and $abab$. Now use some inverses.

Comment: $a * a = 1$ implies $a = a^{-1}$. Use $(a*b)*(a*b) = 1$.

Comment: If you need to show a group is abelian, you can't start by assuming it is abelian!  So your proof looks like: "if G is abelian then G is abelian".

Comment: Yeah xd, I made a mistake. I didn't notice I flipped the numbers I don't know why. That's why I was getting cool results hahahah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 = (ba)(ba)

1 (ab)= baba(ab)

ab = bab (aa)b=bab1b=babb=ba (bb)=ba1=ba